# Error: could not get audio input stream from input file from code? What's wrong with code?

Tags: java, swing

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.io.*;
import javax.sound.sampled.*;

public class AudioTest extends JFrame implements ActionListener
{
AudioFormat audioFormat;
AudioInputStream audioInputStream;
SourceDataLine sourceDataLine;
boolean stopPlayback = false;
private final JButton stopBtn = new JButton("Stop");
private final JButton playBtn = new JButton("Play");
private final JTextField textField = new JTextField("junk.au");

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    AudioTest gui = new AudioTest();
    gui.setVisible(true);
}

public AudioTest()
{
    stopBtn.setEnabled(false);
    playBtn.setEnabled(true);

    playBtn.addActionListener(this);

    stopBtn.addActionListener(this);

    getContentPane().add(playBtn, "West");
    getContentPane().add(stopBtn, "East");
    getContentPane().add(textField, "North");

    setTitle("Audio Test");
    addWindowListener(new WindowDestroyer());
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setSize(250, 70);
}

private void playAudio()
{
    try
    {
        File soundFile = new File(textField.getText());
        audioInputStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(soundFile);
        audioFormat = audioInputStream.getFormat();
        System.out.println(audioFormat);
        DataLine.Info dataLineInfo = new DataLine.Info(SourceDataLine.class,       audioFormat);
        sourceDataLine = (SourceDataLine)AudioSystem.getLine(dataLineInfo);
        new PlayThread().start();
    }

    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.exit(0);
    }
}

private class PlayThread extends Thread
{
    byte tempBuffer[]  = new byte[10000];

    public void run()
    {
        try
        {
            sourceDataLine.open(audioFormat);
            sourceDataLine.start();

            int cnt;

            while((cnt = audioInputStream.read(
                    tempBuffer, 0, tempBuffer.length)) != 1
                        && stopPlayback == false) 
            {
                if(cnt >0)
                {
                    sourceDataLine.write(tempBuffer, 0, cnt);
                }
            }

            sourceDataLine.drain();
            sourceDataLine.close();

            stopBtn.setEnabled(false);
            playBtn.setEnabled(true);
            stopPlayback = false;
        }

        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(0);
                }
            }
        }


public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
{
    if(e.getActionCommand().equals("Play"))
    {
        stopBtn.setEnabled(true);
        playBtn.setEnabled(false);
        playAudio();
    }
    else if(e.getActionCommand().equals("Stop"))
    {
        stopPlayback = true;
    }
}
}
```

I have been on this trying to figure out why there is a problem with the audio input stream. The file name is correct and it takes it into the file, but the line that has the getAudioInputStream has the problem. This a test code for a project I'm planning to work on, I'm familiar with everything, but I keep getting error.

Comment: Did you make sure that the soundfile exists and that you used correct '//' or '\' ?

Comment: "has the problem" is no valid error explanation

Comment: `I keep getting error` What is the error? Can you post stacktrace and what line(s) the errors are on. It's really worthwhile have a read of [how to write a Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/) in order to get the most out of this site and its contributors!

Comment: javax.sound.sampled.UnsupportedAudioFileException: could not get audio input stream from input file
 at javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(Unknown Source)
 at AudioTest.playAudio(AudioTest.java:47)

Comment: Have tried a different file/audio format?

Answer (score 1):

You need to supply the full path and file name, for example...

[image: AudioTest]

works just find...

You might want to consider trying a different audio format (like .wav for example)

Comment: I did supply the full path name and file name, I'm very sure that's not the problem

Comment: Works fine for me...

Comment: Did you use the exact same code I provided? By the way I am using Eclipse(latest version) do you think that might be the source of my problem

Comment: Copy and pasted verbatim, only removed `addWindowListener(new WindowDestroyer())`

Comment: You are exactly right sir, It plays wav files, but not mp3 files. I downloaded a wav file and it worked. Thanks for the insight. Do you have any idea as to if the same code can play mp3 with a little tweaking??

Comment: No, the in built Audio API only plays a limited set of audio formats (it might play SOME MP3 files but not all).  You consider having a look at [this](http://www.javazoom.net/mp3spi/mp3spi.html)  instead

Comment: I even tried using .au and it seemed to work just fine for me...